# Is there an operator to specify an index "not less than 0"?

Tags: python

To "peek" at characters in a string preceding the current index, `i`, is there a one-liner for avoiding negative indices? I want `n` chars before the current char index of the string OR beginning of the string to current char.

My intuition says there might be something simple I can put in the same line as the list operation instead of another line to make an index. I'd rather avoid any libraries, and I'm aware a simple `if` check would work... Hoping there's a magic operator I missed.

```
>>> s = 'ABCDEFG'
>>> s[0:5]
'ABCDE'
>>> s[-5:5]
'CDE'
```

Comment: I think you'll need an `if` if you want to always start at `0`.

Comment: `s[max(0,i-n): i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
s = 'ABCDEFG'
i = 5
n = 3

print(s[max(0, i-n): i])
```

Output:

```
CDE
```

Comment: totally. thanks! it's unlikely `max()` on two ints would be a bottleneck right?

Comment: true it'd run in constant time, so not an issue. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no operator for doing this, but you can achieve the same effect with `max`:

```
>>> s = 'abcdefg'
>>> i = 3
>>> s[max(i - 6, 0):i + 2]
'abcde'
```

Comment: i think this is the answer, but abhilash got it just a few second earlier; i'll give them the answer. thanks for helping